# Getting the upload progress during file upload using Webclient.Uploadfile

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, webclient

I have an app that uploads files to server using the webclient.
I'd like to display a progressbar while the file upload is in progress.
How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[WebClient.UploadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144232.aspx) will allow you to do this.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.UploadFileAsync(address, fileName);
webClient.UploadProgressChanged += WebClientUploadProgressChanged;
```

...

```
void WebClientUploadProgressChanged(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Upload {0}% complete. ", e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

Note that the thread won't block on Upload anymore, so I'd recommend using:

```
 webClient.UploadFileCompleted += WebClientUploadCompleted;
```

...

```
 void WebClientUploadCompleted(object sender, UploadFileCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     // The upload is finished, clean up
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with multithreading, the file upload is already running on a different thread. So should I just use the Uploadfile method or the UploadfileAsync method?

Comment: You'll still need to UploadFileAsync I'm afraid, the thread will block on a call to UploadFile so those events will never get called. You can recreate your own blocking by setting a bool flag when you start the upload, reset it in uploadcomplete, then thread.sleep until the flag is cleared.

Comment: note: ```UploadProgressChanged```  event does not work well with ```UploadDataAsync``` method

Comment: How to pass parameters like FileName in WebClient?

Comment: Did you use any cancelAsyc in your method. if yes how did you use it in a way the cancel upload stop on the spot and not wait to end the upload process to cancel?

Answer (score 2):

Add your event handler to WebClient.UploadProgressChanged and call WebClient.UploadFileAsync.

See the [WebClient.UploadProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation for an example.