# Upload file - Progress Bar?

Tags: c#, vb.net, upload, progress-bar

I'm trying out uploading of files from local computer to a server and I'm using these few lines of code:

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("C:\Temp\test.mp3", "192.168.1.2\test", "", "", True, 500)
```

This does exactly that and the "True" in the above string shows a progressbar in its own window. I would like for that progressbar to display on the same form as the rest of controls are. And not in it's own window. Is there a way of doing just that?

Comment: Think maybe this is what I'm looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982299/webclient-uploadfile

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is not possible with My.Computer.Network.UploadFile. If you really want to do it maybe get the hWnd of the progressbar on the dialog but thats kind of nasty.