# File upload HTTP PUT in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, file-upload

I am writing a desktop app in C# for upload large sized files on a webserver using HTTP PUT. I have tried libcurl .net but it seems the bindings seem pretty difficult to use.

Is there a better and easier way?

PS: My server is nginx. I believe HTTP PUT is the best way but if there is a better alternative available on nginx, I can use that as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried the built-in [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx), doesn't get much simpler:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadData("http://www.example.com/upload-image", "PUT", imageData);
```

([WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) is also available, which might be even better, depending on where your image data is located)

Comment: Is it also possible to get callbacks to monitor the progress of the upload?

Comment: Oh just noticed it has the callbacks for monitoring progress :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sharjeel: hey, can u post a snippet how to do callbacks for monitoring progress using `WebClient`

Comment: @FosterZ, use UploadFileAsync method and use the UploadProgressChanged delete. Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982299/webclient-uploadfile/982332#982332

Comment: don't forget to call Dispose (or use a Using)